# Quotation problems in results ( python )

Tags: python, python-requests, double-quotes

I hope you can help me with these, I create a script to extract some tables from a DB and after doing that, convert them to JSONL file.

My script work but when comes to the results ( JSONL ), some quotes " remove from the results and I dont know why, my script:

```
import pyodbc
import fileinput
import csv
import pandas as pd
import json
import os
import sys

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=Test;'
                      'UID=test;'
                      'PWD=test;'
                      'Database=TEST;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=no;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM placeholder"


with open(r"D:\Test.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    print(lines)


for user_input in lines:

    result = query.replace("placeholder", user_input)
    print(result)
    sql_query = pd.read_sql(result,conn)
    df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
    user_inputs =  user_input.strip("\n")
    filename = os.path.join('D:\\', user_inputs + '.csv')
    df.to_csv (filename, index = False, encoding='utf-8', sep = '~', quotechar = "`", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    print(filename)
    filename_json = os.path.join('D:\\', user_inputs + '.jsonl')
    csvFilePath = (filename)
    jsonFilePath = (filename_json)
    print(filename_json)
    df.to_json(filename_json, orient = "records",  lines = bool, date_format = "epoch", double_precision = 15, force_ascii = False, date_unit = 'ms', default_handler = str)

dir_name = "D:\\"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".csv"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item))

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Now the results ( example ):

```
{"SucCod":1,"SucNom":"CENTRAL                  ","SucUsrMod":"aleos     ","SucFecMod":1537920000000,"SucHorMod":"11:30:21","SucTip":"S","SucBocFac":4,"SucCal":"SUTH               ","SucNro":1524,"SucPis":6,"SucDto":"    ","SucCarTel":"55   ","SucTel":52001}
```

And I spect ( example ):

```
{"SucCod":"1","SucNom":"CENTRAL                  ","SucUsrMod":"aleos     ","SucFecMod":"1537920000000","SucHorMod":"11:30:21","SucTip":"S","SucBocFac":"4","SucCal":"SUTH               ","SucNro":"1524","SucPis":"6","SucDto":"    ","SucCarTel":"55   ","SucTel":"52001"}
```

Now as you can see some data are missing the quotation "

After checking the CSV file they maintain the quotations so the problem is when converting to JSONL.

Do you have any idea about the switch I need to use to maintain the quotations ???

Thanks so much.

Kind regards.

Comment: The only difference between the two datasets is that the one being returned has numeric values represented as ints, not strings. CSV files can handles ints as well as strings, so what exactly is your question? If you *really* want strings, you can easily call `str()` on the numeric values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything in your DataFrame must be a string, try using [DataFrame.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```py
df_o = df.astype(str)
df_o.to_json()
```

otherwise:

```py
df_o = df.astype(object)
df_o.to_json()
```

Comment: Wow, my friend !!!

You are amazing !!! Thanks so much really you help me too much !!!

Kind regards ...

Comment: Glad to help! If that solves mark as solved (and optionally upvote)